# Trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I have been trying to solve this equation for over a week now:
 $$\tan5x-2\tan3x=\tan3x\tan5x$$

I found one solution $x=k\pi$ but I cannot prove that this is the only solution. 
It is equivalent to:
$$\sin 5x \cos 3x - 2 \sin 3x \cos 5x = \sin 3x \sin 5x$$
$$\sin 2x =\sqrt 2 \sin  3x \sin(5x+ \frac{\pi}{4})$$
$$2\sin x \cos x =2\sqrt 2 \sin x \cos (2x +1) \sin(5x+ \frac{\pi}{4})$$
 So one solution is $x=k\pi$.
 But how to proceed with the remaining:
$$\sqrt 2 \cos x = 2\cos (2x +1) \sin(5x+ \frac{\pi}{4}) $$
It seems impossible to use derivatives to prove that it has no solution because the argument of the third cosine is shifted by $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: What does tg5x mean ?

Comment: is tg= trigonometric?

Comment: Corrected. It means tan5x

Comment: Wolfram Alpha thinks there are more solutions (none of which --apart from the multiplies of $\pi$-- are very attractive): http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+of+tan%285x%29-2+tan%283x%29-+%28tan%283x%29%29%28tan%285x%29%29

Comment: @Blue: do you mind making your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply
$$
\tan(5x)-2\tan(3x)=\tan(3x)\tan(5x)
$$
by $\cos(3x)\cos(5x)$ and cancel to get
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\sin(5x)\cos(3x)-2\sin(3x)\cos(5x)-\sin(3x)\sin(5x)\\
&=\tfrac12(\sin(8x)+\sin(2x))-2\cdot\tfrac12(\sin(8x)-\sin(2x))-\tfrac12(\cos(2z)-\cos(8x))\\
&=\tfrac12(\cos(8x)-\sin(8x)+3\sin(2x)-\cos(2x))\\
&=\tfrac12(\sqrt2\sin(8x+\tfrac34\pi)+\sqrt{10}\sin(2x-\arctan(\tfrac13)))\\
\end{align}
$$
There doesn't appear to be any simple way to solve this other than numerically.

The function has a period of $\pi$. Plotting, it appears that this function has $4$ roots in $[0,\pi)$.

$\hspace{8mm}$[image]

Numerically, the roots in $[0,\pi)$ are
$$
x=\left\{\begin{array}{}
0.0000000000000000000\\
0.3598476319540602998\\
1.6915164344292107407\\
3.0829964597422711815
\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Making my comment into an answer, as requested:

Wolfram Alpha thinks there are more solutions (none of which ---apart from the multiples of $\pi$--- are very attractive). [See here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots%20of%20tan%285x%29-2%20tan%283x%29-%20%28tan%283x%29%29%28tan%285x%29%29)